# Acr.UserDialogs in MVVMCross: problems with the notification

Tags: android, notifications, xamarin.android, dialog, mvvmcross

I have Xamarin Android project and use MVVMCross.

I need to show the notification. It should be the text and the image. I created the .axml file with it and I need to show it after the click of the button.

I did research here and found [Acr.UserDialogs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/). I installed it:

```
PM> Install-Package Acr.UserDialogs -Version 7.0.0
```

In one of `...View.axml` I have the button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/enterButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/resendCodeLink"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    local:MvxBind="Text Strings[EnterButton]; Click EnterCommand" />
```

I'd like the user to see the notification window after click this button. I add the logic to `ViewModel.cs`:

```
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using System.Windows.Input;
using MvvmCross.Platform;

namespace My.Hello.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class HellooneViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ICommand EnterCommand => new MvxCommand(() => {
        Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().Alert("message");
    });
    }
}
```

But I need notification that looks like this (instead of only one string). How can I add in Alert showing this `notification.axml`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="114dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/noticeText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Hello" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/noticeImage"
    android:src="@mipmap/my_ic_90dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="95dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="103dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So I try to use Acr.UserDialogs. My `App.cs`:

```
using MvvmCross.Platform;
using MvvmCross.Platform.IoC;

namespace My.Hello.Core
{
    public class App : MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxApplication
    {
        public object UserDialogs { get; set; }

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            CreatableTypes()
                .EndingWith("Service")
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

            Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IUserDialogs>(() => UserDialogs.Instance);

            RegisterCustomAppStart<AppStart>();
        }
    }

    internal interface IUserDialogs
    {
        void Alert(string v);
    }
}
```

And one more problem is `Instance` has red underline with exception: "object does not contain a definition for instance..." What instance should I create and how?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because `UserDialogs` is of type `object` that you created in that class. Instead you should call it like so: `Acr.UserDialogs.Instance` (it may be all-caps `ACR.UserDialogs.Instance`, I can't remember exactly)

The `public object UserDialogs { get; set; }` is not needed.

Comment: Oh, really, thank you! And can you please give me an advice how to show my .axml instead of `Alert("message")`